# Advertisement stretching the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

Using Firefox 3.6, some Home4Film advertisements are stretching the entire page:

[image: here].

I get the same behavior in Opera, IE8, and Chrome.

Comment: There are 3 ads in total, one banner and two sidebar, and the filenames are quite similar. I also saw a sidebar ad in the banner position which looked interesting. Anyway I think it looks quite striking, it certainly highlights the ad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's apparently an image that is meant for the advertisement banner above the question and in between answers, and it ended up in the sidebar in stead. Someone must have mixed them up.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed!**

(and now the body is not too short to post as an answer)